Earliest paper on stratified log rank test
What is the earliest paper that proposed the stratified version of the log-rank test?
Unfortunately, finding citations/references in textbooks for established statistics procedures is difficult.

As mentioned by Jun Shao in his paper, it was by R Peto et al. in their paper  Design and analysis of randomized clinical trials requiring prolonged observation of each patient. I. Introduction and design, the description being found in PubMed site.
--
In fact, Peto & Peto in an earlier paper Asymptotically Efficient Rank Invariant Test Procedures, used the term log-rank for their invariant rank based statistic. Later, they generalized for "multi-group experiments".

I have already reviewed this reference, and I do not see any section discussing the development of the statistic in question.

Check their earlier paper linked above.

No, it's much earlier by Nathan-Mantel under the Mantel-Haenszel framework.

Yes, @FrankHarrell, you are right in that Peto wasn't the first in developing the statistic based on chi square (even Peto cited their 1959 paper) . But it was Peto's 1972 paper, which according to Kalbfleisch and Prentice, was the first to "coin the term log-rank".
